# Meteor - Errors prevented startup after importing variable in methods.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to call an async function that resides in a path (namely imports/ui/pages/plan-selection.js)
from a server method, that resides in a different path,( namely imports\api\exports\methods.js)
so I exported the async function as a variable such as:

> module.exports.search_for_products=search_for_products;

and then imported it into the methods.js file:

> import {search_for_products } from ‘…/…/ui/pages/plan-selection.js’;

after that importing I start getting the below error[image]

To notice here that in the file plan-selection.js there is a line

> import ‘./plan-selection.html’;

I tried including the plan-selection.html or plan-selection.js in some directory files such as server/index.js but did not have any results, do you have any suggestions why this happens and what should I do?

Comment: Is a `plan-selection.html` in the same directory as a `plan-selection.js`? Have you tried to use absolute path for importing?

Comment: @extempl it is, but I believe the error came out of that plan-selection.js had mixed code logic and template blaze logic so I should remove this particular function in a separate file so that can be used for both client and server side purposes. Given that I believe the right would be to include it in methods.js file is that correct from my understanding?